# What will happen if we store a value in carry register in 8051?

Tags: assembly, 8051, microprocessors

When I write this code in 8051 simulator:

```
MOV 07h, #45h
MOV C, 07h
```

It works and make the carry bit zero. But what does this code do, and why carry bit is zero?

Comment: @Jester Thank you is it means that 20h 's 7th bit in RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are observing is accidental. The `07h` in the two instructions is not the same. The first one is byte address, the second one is bit address which is actually the most significant bit of byte address `20h`.